# Is there a way to mirror a matrix of data then convert to an x, y coordinate array?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to take a matrix of data points where values in column 2 are always >= values in column 1, hence creating a triangular array. I need to create a square array with data mirrored across the diagonal. For example, the value at [1,3] and [3,1] would be the same. I have a three column matrix where the first column is the X-coordinate, second column is the Y-coordinate, and the third column is a specific value, like this:

```
1  1  1.5
1  2  2.3
1  3  3.3
2  2  5.6
2  3  2.1
3  3  1.0
3  4  0.7
3  5  4.1
3  6  2.9
```

There are missing values in columns 1 and 2 so after I mirrored the matrix and merge so that I get the square array of data I want, I am filling in missing indices with 0. First the script is getting a "counts per million" value for each value in the third column. I've seen some variations on certain parts of this but nothing that gives what I need.

```
with open(args.matrix, 'r') as mtx:
    df = pd.read_csv(mtx, sep='\t', lineterminator='\n', header=None)
    num = df[2].sum(axis=0)
    df[2] = (df[2]/num)*1000000
    df[0] = df[0]-1
    df[1] = df[1]-1
    df2 = df[[1,0,2]].rename({1:0, 0:1}, axis='columns')
    df2 = df2[df2[0] != df2[1]]
    df = pd.concat([df,df2]).sort_values([0,1], ascending=[True,True], ignore_index=True)
    df = df.pivot(index=1, columns=0, values=2).fillna(0).reindex(index=range(1,num), columns=range(1,num), fill_value=0)
```

The script does work, but is there a faster, more elegant way to perform this task? I'm not sure if I am explaining this well enough so please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that would work because I don't want the third element in my array to move. If there is a way to flip just the first two elements, that might work.

Comment: Just slice the subarray, flip, flip and np.where to fill the original with the flipped

Comment: Yeah I suppose that would work. Would creating an array and flipping twice work better than my answer below (just iterating over the input matrix)? I'm just trying to find the fastest way to do this since my matrices are huge and I do several of them at a time.

Comment: there is no doubt using numpy functions would be faster than looping, exponentially on scale, as they work in C.

Comment: and they also have the advantage of not having to copy the actual data most of the time, just referring to the same object in memory but with a different view

Answer (score 0):

This is based more around numpy as an alternate.

```
import itertools
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""1  1  1.5
1  2  2.3
1  3  3.3
2  2  5.6
2  3  2.1
3  3  1.0
3  4  0.7
3  5  4.1
3  6  2.9"""), header=None, sep="\s+")


num = df[2].sum(axis=0)
df[2] = (df[2]/num)*1000000
df[0] = df[0]-1
df[1] = df[1]-1
# get valid permutations of x and y so can by uniform n*n matrix
num = max(df[0].max(),df[1].max())+1
# need to add the diaganol on top of permutations
perms = list(itertools.permutations([n for n in range(num)],2)) + [(n,n) for n in range(num)]

# change to a multi-index, x,y 
df = df.set_index([0,1]).rename(columns={2:"val"})
# make uniform n*n
df = df.reindex(perms).unstack().fillna(0)
# "flip" in values that are in equivalent cell....
# no need to create df,  just convenient for visualisation...
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.values==0, df.values.T, df.values))
# don't get this requirement but if you want to pad out...
biggernum = 25
pd.DataFrame(np.pad(df.values, ((0,biggernum-num),(0,biggernum-num))))
```

Comment: This was somewhat helpful, but didn't work with my larger matrices. I kept getting this error: 
`MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.45 PiB for an array with shape (14290643, 14290643) and data type float64`

Comment: Hey I've updated and simplified answer.  I think that error is coming because you were re-sizing in this way so when I refactored I copied....   I couldn't see logic to resize matrix based on `df[2].sum(axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments and suggestions. What I ended up doing is iterating over the input matrix to create the array then performing the "counts per million" calculation. I know it's not good practice to iterate over an array/dataframe, so I didn't want to iterate after converting to a data frame and performing the calculation. However, I figured that iterating prior to creating the array might work better/faster; and it did. Here's my updated script (I just put num=2500 for simiplicity; there's a function that precedes this script).:

```
num = 2500
mat = np.zeros((num,num))
with open(args.matrix, 'r') as mtx:
    for i in csv.reader(mtx, delimiter="\t"):
        mat[int(i[0])-1][int(i[1])-1] = i[2]
        mat[int(i[1])-1][int(i[0])-1] = i[2]
    reads = np.sum(mat)
    mat = mat/(reads*0.000001)
```

As I stated in one of my comments, I'm trying to make this run as fast as possible. The matrices I'm using are usually tens of thousands of lines long, thus the arrays are at minimum 2000 x 2000, and I do several at a time. If anyone has any suggestions for ways to decrease runtime, please let me know.